# How can I make conformal thin layers on existing geometry, i.e. coatings with volume?

Tags: modeling

I am very new to Blender and modelling in general, but there's a pretty specific type of model I'd like to make and play with in different forms- thin films coating different geometries (which I can slice and render from different directions).

For example, I'd like to replicate something like this image:

[image: example]

Where the underlying geometry is a block with trenches in it, and they've added colored conformal layers on top.

I understand how to make the basic shape, but finding a good way to make the coating layers eludes me. Extruding just makes the basic shape bigger, and I need different regions to which I can assign different colors/materials.

For example, if I've made something like this:

[image: example2]

and I'd like to add a conformal layer to the top and inside walls of the depression (to be arrayed afterward), how can I best do this?

Comment: Have you looked into the [Solidify](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html) modifier? It allows you to add a constant thickness to an existing shape or geometry. If you already have a base object you can do it non destructively allowing you to dynamically edit it without having to do it all over again.

Comment: solidify modifier or/and shrinkwrap with offset